# Inheriting and extending constraints in generics

Tags: c#

I have a base generic class that looks something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseTestDataEntity<T>
      where T : IIdEntity, ICodeEntity, IActiveEntity, new()
   {
}
```

These interfaces represent fields in data entities.This is very useful because using these interfaces I can write generic base classes which can have methods like Add, Update, etc.

But what's really useful is full design time support based on the contracts in the interfaces.

An example of an instance:

```
public class Customer : BaseTestDataEntity<Customer>
   {}
```

Now I have a situation where I would like to create a derived class of BaseTestDataEntity which will include all the constraints of base (so per the code, T must have an id, code, and active flag)

However in the derived class I want to add additional constraints.

This way I don't have to duplicate the concrete methods in BaseTestDataEntity.

What I have tried and what I want to do:

```
public class BaseTestDataEntityImpl<T>
   : BaseTestDataEntity<T> where T : IIdEntity, ICodeEntity, IMultiTextEntity, IActiveEntity, new()

   {
       // This should enforce T constaints in the base class, but where do I put in new constraints in the derived T?
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but in your code, all the constraints only affect derived `BaseTestDataEntityImpl<T>`. They are not passed down the inheritance chain down to `BaseTestDataEntity`.

To make it a bit more clear, let's assume I have following class:

```
public class FooHandler<T> where T : IFoo {}
```

and now I want to have another class that inherits `FooHandler`, but also requires it's generic argument to implement `IBar`.

```
public class FooAndBarHandler<TFooAndBar> where TFooAndBar : IFoo, IBar
```

As you see, I even named the generic parameter differently, because they are actually different. `TFooAndBar` and it's constraint has nothing to do with `TFoo` from the class `FooAndBarHandler` derives from. You do have to make sure that whatever you pass to `FooHandler` does implement `IFoo`, and that's why in that case `TFooAndBar` has to implement `TFoo`. But there are other ways of fullfiling that base class generic constraint. If you assume following situation:

```
interface IFoo {}
interface IBar : IFoo {}
```

you'd be able to just write

```
public class BarHandler<TBar> : FooHandler<TBar> where TBar : IBar
```

because `TBar : IBar` constraint already forces `TBar` to also implement `IFoo`.

Or you could hardcode `FooHandler<MyFooImplementation>`:

```
public class BarHandler<TBar> : FooHandler<MyFooImplementation> where TBar : IBar
```